# angularjs directive click outside to close pop-up (Try to do different ways)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

As the question asks, I want to rewrite the directive (click outside to close pop-up) in different way. Such as using different methods other than scope.$watch and use more easy-readable codes. Please give some suggestions on that. Link of snippet: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HIaS.png)

Directive:

```
angular.module('WSBXApp.Directives')
.directive('wsbxOutsideClick', ['$document', function ($document, $event) {
    return {
        link : function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var onClick = function (e) {
                var targetNode = $((e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0] : e).target);
                if (!targetNode.closest($(element)).length && !targetNode.closest(scope.$ctrl.display.element).length) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.wsbxOutsideClick);
                }
            };
            console.log(attrs.display);
            scope.$watch(attrs.display, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue && newValue == true) {
                    $document.bind('click', onClick);
                    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ scope.$apply(attrs.wsbxOutsideClick); }, true);
                }
                else if (newValue !== oldValue && newValue == false) {
                    $document.unbind('click', onClick);
                    window.removeEventListener('scroll', function(){ scope.$apply(attrs.wsbxOutsideClick); }, true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="label popup-container popup-tooltip hidden-xs" ng-style="$ctrl.display.position" wsbx-outside-click="$ctrl.close()" ng-show="$ctrl.display.is_display" display="$ctrl.display.is_display">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below..

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['outsideClick']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var ctrl = {
    popupVisible: false,
  };

  ctrl.showPopup = function() {
    ctrl.popupVisible = true;
  };
  ctrl.hidePopup = function() {
    ctrl.popupVisible = false;
  };

  return ctrl;
});

(function () {
    var module = angular.module('outsideClick', []);
    var directiveName='outSideClick';
    module.directive(directiveName, ['$document', "$parse", function ($document, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link:  function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
                var anyOtherClickFunction = $parse(attr[directiveName]);
                var documentClickHandler = function (event) {
                    var eventOutsideTarget = (element[0] !== event.target) && (0 === element.find(event.target).length);
                    if (eventOutsideTarget) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            anyOtherClickFunction(scope, {});
                        });
                    }
                };

                $document.on("click", documentClickHandler);
                scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
                    $document.off("click", documentClickHandler);
                });
            },
        };
    }]);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
<style>

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.popup {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0.75em;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding:4px;
}</style>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <div>
    <a ng-click="ctrl.showPopup(); $event.stopPropagation()">Show Popup</a>
 <div class="popup" ng-show="ctrl.popupVisible" out-side-click="ctrl.hidePopup()">
      <strong>Popup Visible!</strong>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div>Clicks inside the popup do not dismiss</div>
      <br />
      <a ng-click="ctrl.hidePopup()">Hide Popup (or outside) to dismiss</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```